# Retrieving data from a URL using Alamofire in Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to send a request with Alamofire to a URL that contains JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "code": 11,
  "responseTS": 1587219531266,
  "message": "not running",
  "version": "2.1",
  "command": "http://www.url.com",
  "status": "NotRunning"
}
```

This is my function. Now, it prints the response, but stops and doesn't complete the rest of the code. Because the message in the JSON is "not running", it should call getDBLocation(), but it stops after printing the response (before the guard statement). Can anyone tell me why this might be happening?

XCode gives no errors, and the application doesn't crash, it just doesn't continue the function like I expect it to.

```
 func checkStatus() {
            let url = qpeUrl

            Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (response) in

                print(response)
                print(response.result)

                guard response.result.error == nil else {
                  print("error")
                  print(response.result.error!)
                  return
                }


                guard let tagStatus = response.result.value as? [String: Any] else {
                    self.audioFail.play()
                    let alertConn = UIAlertController(title: "ERROR!", message:
                            "Couldn't connect", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertConn.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "完了", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alertConn, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    self.captureSession.startRunning()

                    return
                }

                if let tagstatus = tagStatus["message"] as? String {

                    if tagstatus.contains("Unknown") || tagstatus.contains("not running"){

                        self.getDBLocation()
                    }

                }

                if let tagstatus = tagStatus["message"] as? String {

                    if tagstatus.contains("TagPosition") {
                        self.audioSuccess.play()

                        self.sendQPERequest()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Sorry for asking a question that has probably been asked before. I think I'm missing something obvious because it was working previously. However, after trying to fix it for a few weeks, I really can't figure out what's going on.

Edit: The code seems to run ok, only if I step through it. If I don't step through it, it prints SUCCESS (print(response.result)) and then stops before the first guard statement. The code can work through stepping, so I really don't know what is going on.

Comment: What do you expect your code to do? Did you step through the code and see what could be going on?

Comment: Would you please check the response result is a success or not by using this `response.result`?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question @koen . When I step through, it prints the JSON response and then stops, with no error.

Comment: I have checked it and response.result is a success. It is a GET request. I am trying to check the value of "message" in the JSON. @FaysalAhmed

Comment: if the response printed successfully then `self.getDBLocation()` method should call.

Comment: That's what I thought...it was working a few weeks ago, but now it doesn't get past print(response). No error, the application doesn't crash. I'm not very familiar with guard statements, so I thought that might be causing it. It isn't very helpful sorry, but I appreciate your help. Thank you. @FaysalAhmed

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'it stops', does it not get past the `guard let tagStatus` line? That could mean that `response.result.value as? [String: Any]` is nil.

Comment: Seems like the response is not success.

Comment: Unrelated, I’d advise against multiple `if let tagstatus = tagStatus["message"] as? String { ... }`, but rather do that once (or use `guard let tagstatus = tagStatus["message"] as? String else { return }` pattern, again, doing it only once).